# convert rows from dataframe to columns, matching row on a shared column value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Suppose I have a dataframe like this (extracted from key/value SQL table):

```
id     | key | value
------------------------
abc123 | foo | "horse"
abc123 | bar | 42
def456 | foo | "zebra"
def456 | foo | 101
```

I'd like to convert to a dataframe that pivots on the `id` column, using the **values** of `key` as new column names:

```
id     | foo     | bar
------------------------
abc123 | "horse | 42
def456 | "zebra" | 101
```

Is [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) what I'm looking for?  Always had a hard time with my pivot intuition...

Any suggestions on how to do this idiomatic pandas way?  Thanks.

Comment: yop, need `pivot`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, was literally just answering my own question with a `df.pivot` that did precisely that.